# Return TSubType from nhibernate QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, hql, queryover, nhibernate-criteria

I am trying to select the children from a parent collection using QueryOver in nhibernate.
This is what I am trying to do in HQL:

```
SELECT as_kitten FROM Cat as_Cat 
JOIN as_Cat.Kittens as_kitten
```

How does this translate to QueryOver or even using JoinAlias?

```
IList<Kitten> kittens =  session.QueryOver<Cat>()
        .JoinQueryOver<Kitten>(c => c.Kittens)
        .Select(??)
        .List()
```

The closest thing I could find so far is [NHibernate QueryOver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610531/nhibernate-queryover)

Cheers

**EDIT**
Assuming this is a one way relationship, ie. kittens dont' know about cat

Comment: Is there a one to many relationship between Cat and Kittens (or in your case)?

Comment: Yeah there is a one to many relationship. Taken the example from http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example seems rather trivial.  If you already have the parent and have the collection mapped as a one to many inside your cat entity then all you would have to do if you were lazy loading is access the collection.

If you only have the id of the parent you could easily do something like this without even needing a join:

```
IList<Kitten> kittens =  session.QueryOver<Kitten>()
        .Where(k => k.CatId == <parent cat id here>)
        .List<Kitten>()
```

Comment: Thats what I have at the moment. I had to make the relationship bidirectional, but the real domain model has the relationship only one way. Is there a way to do this for a one way model? (I should have said one way relationship in my question, sorry about that). I'l make this the answer if there is no way to do this.